# Send message to a channel without any event

Tags: discord.js

How do I send a message to a channel in Discord.js, where there is no event to trigger it?
So far I've tried

```js
// notify.js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

/*
* @param {string} msg
*/
module.exports = function(msg) {
    client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
    client.channels.cache.get("<channel id>").send(msg);
}
```

which is called from another js file called index.js which calls the function on a HTTP POST request:

```js
// index.js
const express = require('express');
const notify = require('./notify');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    notify(req.body);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(8000);
```

On `POST`ing to the server it throws this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Comment: This may be because your `client.channels.cache.get("<channel id>")` might be undefined. Try adding ternary operators to it, like `client && client.channels && client.channels.cache && client.channels.cache.get('<channel id>') && client.channels.cache.get('channel id').send(msg)`. Though this might not solve it, but won't give error while in production...

Comment: thats pretty bad thing, cause your logging in everytime the function get called, and you only have 1000 logins per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this?

```js
// notify.js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
/*
* @param {string} msg
*/
module.exports = async function(msg) {
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch("<channel id>")
    if(!channel) return; // if the channel is not in the cache return and do nothing
 channel.send(msg);

}
```

i Made the `client.channels.cache.get` to `fetch` method which returns a promise, so you have to make the function async and await it, this fetches the channel from the cache and if its not in the cache gets it from the api

[docs on fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch)

As i said in the comment, your logging in everytime you call the function, and you only have 1000 logins per day, so you easily hit that limit,
after trying out post a comment if it did work or not, and ill update accordingly,

`also its pretty hard to do this without a event as discord.js takes some time to cache everything, so when you call the function, the channel might not be in the cache`

^^ forgot to update with code for future users, since i edited it to fetch, it will not matter, as fetch will get the channel from discord api if its not in cache

Comment: Well that's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: np ; ) lol you could do some imrpovements to this, but for a base this okay